# keep a form on top of other and stay focussed always

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, pascal

I have form1 and form2 in my DXE2 application. Form2 is shown by Form1. Is it possible for me to keep the form2 always on top and stay focused over Form1?. The main idea is, even if the user clicks on form1, focus should remain on form2 and the form2 should blink to inform the user that the form2 needs to be closed first to make Form1 active. Can I achieve this in Delphi?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ShowModal` method of Form2.

Comment: Also set the FormStyle for fsStayOnTop to avoid a fight with other possible Modal windows...